# Casimir energy vs Helmholtz free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, energy, vacuum, casimir-effect

In what way are the Casimir energy and Helmholtz free energy related / do they differ?

In QFT one can compute the Helmholtz free energy as the vacuum expectation value of the zero point function. This seems to capture the same information as the Casimir energy.

Answer (score 1):

We can write the internal energy of a system as $U=U_{\rm Casimir} + U'$, where $U'$ is the sum of all non-Casimir contributions to the energy.

Then the Helmholz free energy is
\begin{equation}
F = U - TS = U_{\rm Casimir} + U' - TS
\end{equation}
where $T$ is the temperature and $S$ the entropy.

So, they are related, in the sense that the Casimir energy contributes to the internal energy and therefore the free energy, but they are not the same.